# Failed to convert string to Tag in C# (ix developer)

Tags: c#

iX developer is a software which uses C# Scripting and I am Trying to pass Tag name as string in order to fetch its value on button click event. While compiling it gets compiled with zero error but when I click on button at the runtime throws

> Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Please help me where and what I am doing wrong.

[This](https://www.beijerelectronicsinc.com/support/ix/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=281&hilit=loop) is my Code and Log File please help and link I am referring

```css
namespace Neo.ApplicationFramework.Generated
{
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Common.Graphics.Logic;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls;
    using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Interfaces;
    
   using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools.OpcClient;
   using System.Reflection;
    
    public partial class Screen1
    {
      
      void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
      {
         
GetGlobalDataItem("value1").Value = 20;
      
      }
      
      private GlobalDataItem GetGlobalDataItem(string propertyName)
      {
         PropertyInfo tagProperty = typeof(Neo.ApplicationFramework.Generated.Tags).GetProperty(propertyName);
         if(tagProperty == null)
            return null;
         else
            return tagProperty.GetValue(Globals.Tags, null) as GlobalDataItem;         
      }
    }
}
```

```css
[Header Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1]
2016-01-16 10:06:42,374 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: PlatformFactoryToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,402 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: FeatureSecurityToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,405 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: StorageToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,461 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SqlCeDatabaseTool
2016-01-16 10:06:42,495 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SQLiteDatabaseTool
2016-01-16 10:06:42,497 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SplashServiceTool
2016-01-16 10:06:42,497 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: DatabaseToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,498 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: MultiLanguageToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,498 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: MessageBoxToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,500 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: OpcClientToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,501 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SystemTagToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,504 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: StorageClientToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,504 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: NonVolatileToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,505 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: ProjectTool
2016-01-16 10:06:42,506 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: AlarmTool
2016-01-16 10:06:42,506 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: AuditTrailToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,517 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: BacklightTool
2016-01-16 10:06:42,519 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: BrandTool
2016-01-16 10:06:42,520 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: CachedDataItemToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,521 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: DateTimeEditToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,522 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: DebugLoggerTool
2016-01-16 10:06:42,523 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: DeviceManagerToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,523 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: DriverPropertiesToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,524 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: EmailSenderTool
2016-01-16 10:06:42,525 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: LicenseToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,525 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: NativeToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,525 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: NetworkToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,526 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: PrinterToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,527 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: ProjectInformationToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,527 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: RecipeToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,528 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: RenderableControlTool
2016-01-16 10:06:42,529 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: CommandLineTool
2016-01-16 10:06:42,530 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: MessageFilterTool
2016-01-16 10:06:42,532 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: NotifierService
2016-01-16 10:06:42,532 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: PrintScreenToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,533 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: TimerToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,534 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: Run
2016-01-16 10:06:42,534 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SimulationTool
2016-01-16 10:06:42,535 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: ScreenManager
2016-01-16 10:06:42,537 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SecurityManagerToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,537 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: ObjectSerializationToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,538 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SMSSenderTool
2016-01-16 10:06:42,538 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: StorageCacheTool
2016-01-16 10:06:42,538 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: StructuredTypesToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,540 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SymbolService
2016-01-16 10:06:42,542 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SystemInformationToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,542 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: KeyPanelConfigToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,542 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: ScopeToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,543 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: TimeInformationToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,543 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: TrendDataToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,543 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: WebServerConfigToolCF
2016-01-16 10:06:42,785 [1] INFO  BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx [(null)] - System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'BeHwApi.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx.BeHWAPI_IsOptimus()
   at BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx.IsOptimus()
2016-01-16 10:06:42,789 [1] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Common.Runtime.GlobalsBase [(null)] - Version: 2.20.2296.0
2016-01-16 10:06:42,796 [1] INFO  BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx [(null)] - System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'BeHwApi.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx.BeHWAPI_IsOptimus()
   at BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx.IsOptimus()
2016-01-16 10:06:42,805 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.ToolMgrCF [(null)] - Initializing ToolManager
2016-01-16 10:06:42,882 [1] INFO  BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx [(null)] - System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'BeHwApi.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx.BeHWAPI_IsOptimus()
   at BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx.IsOptimus()
2016-01-16 10:06:43,422 [1] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - Database: Integrity check started.
2016-01-16 10:06:43,426 [1] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - Database: Integrity check finished without errors.
2016-01-16 10:06:43,430 [1] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - Database: Database created.
2016-01-16 10:06:43,578 [1] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - Database: Cleanup started.
2016-01-16 10:06:43,632 [1] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - Database: Cleanup recovered 12480 bytes.
2016-01-16 10:06:43,764 [7] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - NonVolatileDatabase: Integrity check started.
2016-01-16 10:06:43,768 [7] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - NonVolatileDatabase: Integrity check finished without errors.
2016-01-16 10:06:43,769 [7] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - NonVolatileDatabase: Database created.
2016-01-16 10:06:45,238 [1] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools.Reporting.Reports [(null)] - Loading support for reporting with type of FlexCel.XlsAdapter.XlsFile.
2016-01-16 10:06:47,412 [1] ERROR Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools.Backlight.BacklightController [(null)] - Failed to find registryKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\backlight
2016-01-16 10:06:47,412 [1] ERROR Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools.Backlight.BacklightController [(null)] - Failed to find registryKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\backlight
2016-01-16 10:06:47,413 [1] ERROR Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools.Backlight.BacklightController [(null)] - Failed to find registryKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\backlight
2016-01-16 10:06:47,413 [1] ERROR Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools.Backlight.BacklightController [(null)] - Failed to find registryKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\backlight
2016-01-16 10:06:47,414 [1] ERROR Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools.Backlight.BacklightController [(null)] - Failed to find registryKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\backlight
[Header Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1]
2016-01-16 10:49:27,323 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: PlatformFactoryToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,332 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: FeatureSecurityToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,333 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: StorageToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,354 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SqlCeDatabaseTool
2016-01-16 10:49:27,370 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SQLiteDatabaseTool
2016-01-16 10:49:27,371 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SplashServiceTool
2016-01-16 10:49:27,371 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: DatabaseToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,371 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: MultiLanguageToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,371 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: MessageBoxToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,372 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: OpcClientToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,372 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SystemTagToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,373 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: StorageClientToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,373 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: NonVolatileToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,374 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: ProjectTool
2016-01-16 10:49:27,374 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: AlarmTool
2016-01-16 10:49:27,375 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: AuditTrailToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,378 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: BacklightTool
2016-01-16 10:49:27,379 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: BrandTool
2016-01-16 10:49:27,379 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: CachedDataItemToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,380 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: DateTimeEditToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,380 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: DebugLoggerTool
2016-01-16 10:49:27,380 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: DeviceManagerToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,380 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: DriverPropertiesToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,380 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: EmailSenderTool
2016-01-16 10:49:27,381 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: LicenseToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,381 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: NativeToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,381 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: NetworkToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,382 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: PrinterToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,382 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: ProjectInformationToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,382 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: RecipeToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,383 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: RenderableControlTool
2016-01-16 10:49:27,383 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: CommandLineTool
2016-01-16 10:49:27,383 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: MessageFilterTool
2016-01-16 10:49:27,385 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: NotifierService
2016-01-16 10:49:27,385 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: PrintScreenToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,385 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: TimerToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,386 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: Run
2016-01-16 10:49:27,386 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SimulationTool
2016-01-16 10:49:27,386 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: ScreenManager
2016-01-16 10:49:27,387 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SecurityManagerToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,387 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: ObjectSerializationToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,387 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SMSSenderTool
2016-01-16 10:49:27,388 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: StorageCacheTool
2016-01-16 10:49:27,388 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: StructuredTypesToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,389 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SymbolService
2016-01-16 10:49:27,389 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: SystemInformationToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,389 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: KeyPanelConfigToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,390 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: ScopeToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,390 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: TimeInformationToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,390 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: TrendDataToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,390 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.Tools [(null)] - Loaded tool: WebServerConfigToolCF
2016-01-16 10:49:27,635 [1] INFO  BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx [(null)] - System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'BeHwApi.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx.BeHWAPI_IsOptimus()
   at BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx.IsOptimus()
2016-01-16 10:49:27,637 [1] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Common.Runtime.GlobalsBase [(null)] - Version: 2.20.2296.0
2016-01-16 10:49:27,643 [1] INFO  BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx [(null)] - System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'BeHwApi.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx.BeHWAPI_IsOptimus()
   at BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx.IsOptimus()
2016-01-16 10:49:27,650 [1] INFO  Core.Engine.ToolManager.Private.ToolMgrCF [(null)] - Initializing ToolManager
2016-01-16 10:49:27,678 [1] INFO  BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx [(null)] - System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'BeHwApi.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx.BeHWAPI_IsOptimus()
   at BeHwApiProvider.LegacyToBeIncorporatedWithinIBeHwApiInTheLongRun.BeHwApiEx.IsOptimus()
2016-01-16 10:49:27,856 [1] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - Database: Integrity check started.
2016-01-16 10:49:27,857 [1] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - Database: Integrity check finished without errors.
2016-01-16 10:49:27,858 [1] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - Database: Database created.
2016-01-16 10:49:27,910 [1] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - Database: Cleanup started.
2016-01-16 10:49:27,922 [1] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - Database: Cleanup recovered 12480 bytes.
2016-01-16 10:49:27,955 [7] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - NonVolatileDatabase: Integrity check started.
2016-01-16 10:49:27,955 [7] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - NonVolatileDatabase: Integrity check finished without errors.
2016-01-16 10:49:27,956 [7] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Storage.Providers.CommonDatabase.CommonDatabaseBase [(null)] - NonVolatileDatabase: Database created.
2016-01-16 10:49:28,218 [1] INFO  Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools.Reporting.Reports [(null)] - Loading support for reporting with type of FlexCel.XlsAdapter.XlsFile.
2016-01-16 10:49:30,324 [1] FATAL Neo.ApplicationFramework.Common.Runtime.GlobalsBase [(null)] - Unhandled Exception causing shutdown.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Generated.Screen1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Report_Template\Screen1.Script.cs:line 19
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls.Script.ButtonCFAdapter.FireClick()
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls.Script.ButtonCFAdapter.y(Object A_0, EventArgs A_1)
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls.Controls.BaseObject.FireClick()
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls.Controls.BaseObject.OnClick(MouseEventArgs e)
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls.Controls.Form.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Common.Utilities.NeoApplication.Run(Type screenType)
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Common.Runtime.GlobalsBase.Go(String executingAssemblyName, String executablePath, String[] args, String[] designersToCreate, String[] preloadScreenList, Func`1 startupobjectProvider)
2016-01-16 10:49:31,623 [1] FATAL Neo.ApplicationFramework.Common.Runtime.GlobalsBase [(null)] - Unhandled Exception causing shutdown.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Generated.Screen1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Report_Template\Screen1.Script.cs:line 19
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls.Script.ButtonCFAdapter.FireClick()
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls.Script.ButtonCFAdapter.y(Object A_0, EventArgs A_1)
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls.Controls.BaseObject.FireClick()
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls.Controls.BaseObject.OnClick(MouseEventArgs e)
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls.Controls.Form.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Common.Utilities.NeoApplication.Run(Type screenType)
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Common.Runtime.GlobalsBase.Go(String executingAssemblyName, String executablePath, String[] args, String[] designersToCreate, String[] preloadScreenList, Func`1 startupobjectProvider)
   at Neo.ApplicationFramework.Generated.Globals.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Report_Template\BuildFiles\Report_Template.cs:line 217
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit old question that I happened to stumble on, but here's for other's who might come across this.

I'm not sure which version of iX Developer OP has used, but at least in 2.20 Tags are stored as public fields, not properties. So OP's code would simply work by switching from property searching to field search:

```
private GlobalDataItem GetGlobalDataItem(string fieldName)
  {
     FieldInfo tagField = typeof(Neo.ApplicationFramework.Generated.Tags).GetField(fieldName);
     if(tagField == null)
        return null;
     else
        return tagField .GetValue(Globals.Tags) as GlobalDataItem;         
  }
```

**However in iX Developer 2.20**
all tags are no longer GlobalDataItems but some are stored as LightweightTags and you cannot really tell which type a tag is before the project is built.  The Tags-class (or rather GlobalController, it's parent class does) also stores the tags in Lists which are easy to look through with LINQ:

```
public VariantValue GetTagValue(string tagName)
    {
        GlobalDataItem normalTag = (GlobalDataItem)Globals.Tags.GlobalDataItems.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == tagName);
        if (normalTag != null)
        {
            return normalTag.Value;
        }

        LightweightTag lightTag = (LightweightTag)Globals.Tags.LightweightTags.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == tagName);
        if (lightTag  != null)
        {
            return lightTag.Value;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

You can easily find stuff like this out by installing like Visual Studio Express and opening the project with it via iX Developer's Debug. There you can find e.g. the GlobalDataItem class and every other class that Beijer hasn't bothered to do any documentation for.

Answer (score 0):

In the event Button1_Click , this line :

```
GetGlobalDataItem("value1").Value = 20;
```

change to

```
var item = GetGlobalDataItem("value1");
if(item!=null){
item.Value = 20;
}
```

or

```
GetGlobalDataItem("value1")?.Value = 20;
```

Comment: I tried but what I see is item is equal to null, but I have cross-checked that Tag name "value1" is present.

Comment: I don't know where GlobalDataItem.cs is present

Comment: You can put the cursor point to GlobalDataItem and press F12 or Right Click your mouse and choose the menu item "Go To Declaration"

Comment: No Not getting Go To Declaration option in it.It is Class Present in Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools.OpcClient

Comment: make sure is there "value1" propery in the class GlobalDataItem. If not use a exists property

Comment: foreach(GlobalDataItem gdi in Globals.Tags.DataItem){
    MessageBox.Show(gdi.Name.ToString());
   } With this I can get the variable name but only of variables having read access right. In my case variables are having readwrite access rights.